# Links to other Document Libraries in Explorer View

Tags: document-library, office-365

I've just played around with my site collection and for a more comfortable way to access them, I want to map only one Network drive per site collection. 
So far so good.

I've created an "Entry"-DocLib with links to all other document libraries on this site collection. But as soon as I access it via the Windows-Explorer, it shows me the links in simple IE-Links and opens it with IE. 
But I want to open all DocLibs direct with the Windows Explorer.

I've played a bit around with the address formatting (@SSL etc.) but nothing worked.

Maybe you can help me? Is there a working solution?